# Overwriting just part of a WordPress PHP function

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, function, google-webfonts

I am using the *Divi* WordPress theme, which adds Google Fonts via a function, in their core.php file.

**Is there a way in PHP / WordPress to override just part of a pre-existing function?** I would like to add something to my child theme's function.php to add additional font weights to the *Montserrat* array.

Sure, I could probably overwrite the entire function, but I was hoping there's a way to edit just the Montserrat array, to add more weight options.

This is the theme's function that adds some pre-set weights:

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'et_builder_get_google_fonts' ) ) :
function et_builder_get_google_fonts() {
    $google_fonts = array(
        'Abel' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'sans-serif',
        ),
        'Amatic SC' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,700',
            'character_set' => 'latin,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Arimo' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,400italic,700italic,700',
            'character_set' => 'latin,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext,greek-ext,cyrillic,greek,vietnamese',
            'type'          => 'sans-serif',
        ),
        'Arvo' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,400italic,700,700italic',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'serif',
        ),
        'Bevan' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Bitter' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,400italic,700',
            'character_set' => 'latin,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'serif',
        ),
        'Black Ops One' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Boogaloo' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Bree Serif' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'serif',
        ),
        'Calligraffitti' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Cantata One' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'serif',
        ),
        'Cardo' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,400italic,700',
            'character_set' => 'latin,greek-ext,greek,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'serif',
        ),
        'Changa One' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,400italic',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Cherry Cream Soda' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Chewy' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Comfortaa' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,300,700',
            'character_set' => 'latin,cyrillic-ext,greek,latin-ext,cyrillic',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Coming Soon' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Covered By Your Grace' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Crafty Girls' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Crete Round' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,400italic',
            'character_set' => 'latin,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'serif',
        ),
        'Crimson Text' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'serif',
        ),
        'Cuprum' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,400italic,700italic,700',
            'character_set' => 'latin,latin-ext,cyrillic',
            'type'          => 'sans-serif',
        ),
        'Dancing Script' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,700',
            'character_set' => 'latin,vietnamese,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Dosis' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,200,300,500,600,700,800',
            'character_set' => 'latin,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'sans-serif',
        ),
        'Droid Sans' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,700',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'sans-serif',
        ),
        'Droid Serif' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,400italic,700,700italic',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'serif',
        ),
        'Francois One' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'sans-serif',
        ),
        'Fredoka One' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'The Girl Next Door' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Gloria Hallelujah' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Happy Monkey' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Indie Flower' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Josefin Slab' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,600,700,700italic,600italic',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'serif',
        ),
        'Judson' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,400italic,700',
            'character_set' => 'latin,vietnamese,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'serif',
        ),
        'Kreon' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,300,700',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'serif',
        ),
        'Lato' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic',
            'character_set' => 'latin,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'sans-serif',
        ),
        'Lato Light' => array(
            'parent_font' => 'Lato',
            'styles'      => '300',
        ),
        'Leckerli One' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Lobster' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext,cyrillic',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Lobster Two' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,400italic,700,700italic',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Lora' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,400italic,700,700italic',
            'character_set' => 'cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,vietnamese,latin,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'serif',
        ),
        'Luckiest Guy' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Merriweather' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,300,900,700',
            'character_set' => 'cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,latin,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'serif',
        ),
        'Metamorphous' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Montserrat' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,700',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'sans-serif',
        ),
        'Noticia Text' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,400italic,700,700italic',
            'character_set' => 'latin,vietnamese,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'serif',
        ),
        'Nova Square' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Nunito' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,300,700',
            'character_set' => 'vietnamese,latin,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'sans-serif',
        ),
        'Old Standard TT' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,400italic,700',
            'character_set' => 'cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,vietnamese,latin,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'serif',
        ),
        'Open Sans' => array(
            'styles'        => '300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800',
            'character_set' => 'latin,cyrillic-ext,greek-ext,greek,vietnamese,latin-ext,cyrillic',
            'type'          => 'sans-serif',
        ),
        'Open Sans Condensed' => array(
            'styles'        => '300,300italic,700',
            'character_set' => 'latin,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext,greek-ext,greek,vietnamese,cyrillic',
            'type'          => 'sans-serif',
        ),
        'Open Sans Light' => array(
            'parent_font' => 'Open Sans',
            'styles'      => '300',
        ),
        'Oswald' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,300,700',
            'character_set' => 'latin,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'sans-serif',
        ),
        'Pacifico' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'vietnamese,latin,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Passion One' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,700,900',
            'character_set' => 'latin,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Patrick Hand' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin,vietnamese,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Permanent Marker' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Play' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,700',
            'character_set' => 'latin,cyrillic-ext,cyrillic,greek-ext,greek,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'sans-serif',
        ),
        'Playfair Display' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,400italic,700,700italic,900italic,900',
            'character_set' => 'latin,latin-ext,cyrillic',
            'type'          => 'serif',
        ),
        'Poiret One' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin,latin-ext,cyrillic',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'PT Sans' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,400italic,700,700italic',
            'character_set' => 'latin,latin-ext,cyrillic',
            'type'          => 'sans-serif',
        ),
        'PT Sans Narrow' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,700',
            'character_set' => 'latin,latin-ext,cyrillic',
            'type'          => 'sans-serif',
        ),
        'PT Serif' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,400italic,700,700italic',
            'character_set' => 'latin,cyrillic',
            'type'          => 'serif',
        ),
        'Raleway' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,100,200,300,600,500,700,800,900',
            'character_set' => 'latin,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'sans-serif',
        ),
        'Raleway Light' => array(
            'parent_font' => 'Raleway',
            'styles'      => '300',
        ),
        'Reenie Beanie' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Righteous' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Roboto' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,100,100italic,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic,900,900italic',
            'character_set' => 'latin,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext,cyrillic,greek-ext,greek,vietnamese',
            'type'          => 'sans-serif',
        ),
        'Roboto Condensed' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic',
            'character_set' => 'latin,cyrillic-ext,latin-ext,greek-ext,cyrillic,greek,vietnamese',
            'type'          => 'sans-serif',
        ),
        'Roboto Light' => array(
            'parent_font' => 'Roboto',
            'styles'      => '100',
        ),
        'Rock Salt' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Rokkitt' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,700',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'serif',
        ),
        'Sanchez' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,400italic',
            'character_set' => 'latin,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'serif',
        ),
        'Satisfy' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Schoolbell' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Shadows Into Light' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Source Sans Pro' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,200,200italic,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,900,900italic',
            'character_set' => 'latin,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'sans-serif',
        ),
        'Source Sans Pro Light' => array(
            'parent_font' => 'Source Sans Pro',
            'styles'      => '300',
        ),
        'Special Elite' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Squada One' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Tangerine' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,700',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Ubuntu' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,300,300italic,400italic,500,500italic,700,700italic',
            'character_set' => 'latin,cyrillic-ext,cyrillic,greek-ext,greek,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'sans-serif',
        ),
        'Unkempt' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,700',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Vollkorn' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,400italic,700italic,700',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'serif',
        ),
        'Walter Turncoat' => array(
            'styles'        => '400',
            'character_set' => 'latin',
            'type'          => 'cursive',
        ),
        'Yanone Kaffeesatz' => array(
            'styles'        => '400,200,300,700',
            'character_set' => 'latin,latin-ext',
            'type'          => 'sans-serif',
        ),
    );

    return apply_filters( 'et_builder_google_fonts', $google_fonts );
}
endif;
```

Comment: You can not override a part of a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'et_builder_google_fonts' filter:

Add this to your functions.php to add an extra weight to the Tangerine font for example:

```
add_filter('et_builder_google_fonts', 'my_custom_google_fonts', 10);

function my_custom_google_fonts($google_fonts) {

    $google_fonts['Tangerine']['styles'] = '300,400,700';

    return $google_fonts;

}
```